# Solving infinite continued fraction with natural logarithm.

Tags: logarithms, continued-fractions

How would one go about solving the following continued fraction?

$$
1+\cfrac{z}{2+\cfrac{z}{3+\cfrac{2^{2} z}{4+\cfrac{2^{2} z}{5+\cfrac{3^{2} z}{6+\cfrac{3^{2} z}{\ldots}}}}}}=\frac{z}{\ln (1+z)}
$$

We know that:

$$
\log (1+z)=\frac{z}{1+K_{k}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right]^{2} z, k+1\right)_{1}^{\infty}} / ; z \notin(-\infty,-1)
$$

...which can be expressed as:

$$
\log (1+z)=\cfrac{z}{1+\cfrac{z}{2+\cfrac{z}{3+\cfrac{2 z}{2+\cfrac{2 z}{5+\cfrac{3 z}{2+\cfrac{3 z}{7+\ldots}}}}}}} / ; z \notin(-\infty,-1)
$$

But how does one deal with dividing this into z, as per the original expression?

Is Pell’s equation of any use?

Note also that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x}{x+1} &=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\left[0 ; a_{1}, \ldots, a_{k}\right]}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_{1}+\frac{1}{\ddots+\frac{1}{a_{k}}}}}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1+a_{1}+\frac{1}{\ddots+\frac{1}{a_{k}}}} \\
&=\left[0 ; a_{1}+1, a_{2} \ldots, a_{k}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$